# Long lived (nonlocal) lambda with captured reference

Tags: c++

**Question updated to show a more complete example.**

I recently found that a library that I am using has a piece of code that implements something similar to the following functionality:

```
class Foo {
   std::function<void()> FuncPtr;
public:
   template <typename Type>
   void setBar(std::set<Type> &bar) {
      FuncPtr = [&bar](){
         //Do something with bar
      };
   }
   void useBar() {
      FuncPtr();
   }
};
```

This seems dangerous to me as it is not possible to guarantee that the variable that `bar` references still exist when `Foo::useBar()` is called. With that said, the requirements upon `bar` was documented.

What is the consensus on capturing references in long lived (nonlocal) lambdas?

When asking the maintainer of the library about having the lambda capture a reference, the reason given was that he wanted to make it possible to modify the variable (that `bar` references) after having called `Foo::setBar()`. An alternative solution to implement the same functionality could be to have `bar` be a `shared_ptr<int>` but maybe this is too heavy handed.

Are there other good alternatives to make the code "safe"?

Comment: I think this is horrible.  What _was_ he thinking?

Comment: I dont even get what that code is supposed to be good for. Its my `bar` that I give you a reference of, so why would I call the libraries `getBar` instead of just using my own `bar` ?

Comment: How "safe" do you want it to be?  Do you really need to keep a reference to the passed in variable?  Perhaps a real use case would help us to better recommend an approach

Comment: This is overcomplicated way of keeping a pointer to `int` in `Foo` which is not a good design either

Comment: This look like a super convoluted way of implementing the behaviour of a pointer. Did someone over there say "no raw pointers" too loudly by any chance?

Comment: I see no difference with just making `int*` a member of the class. It also feels a better, clearer, and more performant approach, since calling functions by pointer is much slower than simply accessing the member (directly or through inlined function)

Comment: To clarify the question, I will modify the example to be a it closer to the actual code. In order to protect the maintainer, I do not want to give you the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing a reference is no more or less dangerous than capturing a pointer. The only difference is that you might be more likely to use a raw pointer with caution and think about its lifetime than you would do with a reference.

As you've said the safe way to do it is to use a `shared_ptr`. Whether that is too heavyweight depends on your application, if you are mostly just calling `useBar()` then dereferencing a `shared_ptr` is fairly inexpensive.